# Browsing VR websites in full screen stereoscopic view

Tags: javascript, three.js, virtual-reality, aframe, webvr

I'm creating a virtual reality website and was wondering how could one make visitors browse from one VR website (A) in full screen stereoscopic view to another VR website (B), without exiting full screen stereoscopic view ? Is it even possible ?
This is how I imagine the "VR" web would look like, but I might be wrong.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In current experimental implementations of the webvr API (https://webvr.info), any website can always call [requestPresent](https://w3c.github.io/webvr/#dom-vrdisplay-requestpresent) to enter VR mode if a headset is available. This is still far from providing a good link traversal experience. A website needs to know what headset was previously used to push the content appropriatley. A [set of events](https://w3c.github.io/webvr/#interface-window) have been recently defined for this purpose but are not still completely implemented by browsers. Additional specifications might be needed to define how browsers should behave when traversing links: How do you communicate the user you changed URL? How are content or HTTP errors notified? What is it displayed in the headset when you leave a site and the new one is still loading? Some discusion is happening here: https://github.com/w3c/webvr/issues/69